# Installing Visual Studio on a Windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, visual-studio

Some colleagues of mine are setting up a Windows server (running a few web applications) and demand that Visual Studio is installed on it. Me and most of my other colleagues are only familiar with Linux servers, where installing an IDE on a server makes zero sense and hence, we are all wondering if that is somewhat common for Windows servers. As far as I gathered, they need it to debug an application that does not start correctly on the server.

So my question is -- does that really make any sense, or should I insist that no VS is installed on a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a production customer-facing server, no, definitely no install of VS.

On a development or staging server, visible only inside the company, yes, that makes sense.